# Combine use of AutoMapper Mapping and EF Select Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have some DB Classes (EF Autogenerated) mapping to DTO's.

I'm wondering if it is possible to map objects from within a complex EF Select Query and use the AutoMapper generated IQueryable for an individual object? From what I can see its only available on the IQueryable Select chain, but not from within the lambda?

I'm not sure I have explained it very well but here's the code I was trying to achieve

The second half of the select query doesn't compile. the Entity Framework Class object (e.g. a.CRMActivity) does not contain an extension method for 'ProjectTo' because its a single object, not IQueryable.

```
--------- MAPPING --------

cfg.CreateMap<Supplier, SupplierDto>().ReverseMap();
cfg.CreateMap<CRMActivity, CrmActivityDto>()
   // ignore RTF notes we will generate client side to reduce network traffic (send plaintext version only)
   .ReverseMap()
   .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.DetailsRtf = src.ActivityText.PlainTextToRtf());
// etc etc


-------- SELECT QUERY --------


        var queryable = repo.DBContext.ProcessItemSupplierOnboardings
            .Where(a => a.SupplierCode == supplierCode)
            .IncludeOptimized(a => a.CRMActivity)
            .IncludeOptimized(a => a.Supplier)
            .IncludeOptimized(a => a.ProcessGroup)
            .IncludeOptimized(a => a.ProcessItemSteps)
            .Select(a => new
            {
                Activity = a.CRMActivity,   // Single object CRMActivity
                Supplier = a.Supplier,      // Single object Supplier
                Group = a.ProcessGroup,     // Single object ProcessGroup
                Steps = a.ProcessItemSteps  // ICollection<ProcessItemStep>

                // Want to do this instead  (Create an extension Method ProjectTo or use something from AutoMapper existing?)
                // This part does not compile because the DB class object does not implement IQueryable.

                Activity = a.CRMActivity.ProjectTo<CrmActivityDto>,
                Supplier = a.Supplier.ProjectTo<SupplierDto>,
                Group = a.ProcessGroup.ProjectTo<ProcessGroupDto>,
                Steps = a.ProcessItemSteps.Select(a => a.ProjectTo<ProcessItemStep>)
            });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Should work fine.  Remember you don't need to `Include` when you use `Select`, and you're assigning a _query_ to `Steps`.  Instead assign a _collection_ by running `.Select(...).ToList()`

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The second half of the select query doesn't compile. the Entity Framework Class object (e.g. a.CRMActivity) does not contain an extension method for 'ProjectTo' because its a single object, not IQueryable. That's what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2):

To leverage `ProjectTo` you need a top-level DTO:

```
[Serializable]
public class OnboardingDTO
{
    public CrmActivityDto CRMActivity { get; set; } 
    public SupplierDto Supplier { get; set; }
    public ProcessGroupDto ProcessGroup { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProcessItemStepDTO> ProcessItemSteps { get ;set; } = new List<ProcessItemStepDTO>();
}
```

Then in your mapping configuration include:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ProcessItemSupplierOnboardings, OnBoardingDTO>();
```

... alongside the other mappings. Automapper will work the necessary types out within the top-level DTO.

Now your query expression:

```
var queryable = repo.DBContext.ProcessItemSupplierOnboardings
    .Where(a => a.SupplierCode == supplierCode)
    .ProjectTo<OnBoardingDTO>(config);
```

No need for `Include` statements when using projections. This assumes `config` is your MapperConfiguration instance containing the various DTO configurations.

One caveat: This statement will probably not gel with EF:

```
.AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.DetailsRtf = src.ActivityText.PlainTextToRtf());
```

You might need to replace this with an `Ignore`, and instead ensure your DTOs have the applicable raw data to generate or substitute what the DTO should reveal.